# App Inventor Bluetooth incamming data error in splite component

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

hi for everyone and thanks for help ...
I have a android application with arduino  project ... to receive serial data from ARDUINO MCU and show it on the mobile screen, but when the data received in the form of sensordata01,sensordata02 with comma delimiter ... I get an error ... "Select list item: List index too large Select list item: Attempt to get item number 2 of a list of length 1: (* empity-string )"

i'm uisng splite and select list item components ...But the problem remained the same ....plz would u please help ...!

this block  i made  it with  bluetooth and split incoming data ...

http://arduino.orgfree.com/error.JPG

Thanks or help

Answer (score 0):

I know its been a while since your post but i was having the same problem, and i fixed mine.
my serial code on my arduino was

```
  Serial.print(counter1);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.println(counter2);
```

i changed it to

```
  Serial.print(counter1);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(counter2);
  Serial.println(",");
```

the first one gave an output of X,X the secound gives out put of X,X, 
It was because for the second list item it was looking for "," at the end and i didnt have it i hope this works for you.